# How to solve: LaTeX Error: File `Amr_Beamer.sty' not found

Tags: pdf

this error is happening in my file, i'm using TeXstudio. Could anyone help me fix it?

[image: screenshot]

I hope the pdf can be generated, because I can't generate the pdf.
I'm trying to compile this file, but I can't due to some problem that I can't solve, it's saying: ! LaTeX Error: File 'Amr_Beamer.sty' not found. a problem I have no idea how to solve.
If anyone can solve it, or understands a little bit of my mistake, please help me. I tried a lot, but nothing worked.

Comment: that means you have `\usepackage{Amr_Beamer}` but do not have the file. It is not a standard file, presumably whatever document you saw that said to use that name will tell you where to get that file.

Comment: Can you please add to your question examples, of what you tried „a lot“? Thank you

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From the screenshot is seems there is a `Amr_Beamer.sty`. But I don't see why it is not found. My only guess would be, that read permission is missing. But IMHO without more information it is almost impossible to help. So I vote to close the question.